# 'React/RCTBridgeDelegate.h' file not found in xcode

Tags: javascript, xcode, react-native

I have made a react native app for android but i need to run that app on mac so what are the files to transfer. I have transfer ios folder on mac but its not running. Its showing the error **'React/RCTBridgeDelegate.h' file not found**

[image: this error is showing]

my Reactnative code is [image: This i am working on microsoft and its working fine with android studio]

But how can i run it on mac using xcode.

Comment: You can add code or error messages to your question instead of screenshots.

Comment: What does your podfile look like?

Comment: I our case we've get same error in two Macs with M1 cpu, and the solution to run the App was through Xcode going to Product, Destination, Destination Architecture and choose Show Rosetta destination. After that, the error stay but the App start running in emulator.

Comment: @SebastianDiaz Thank you for the suggestion, this actual helped me to resolve running app from Xcode.

Answer (score 9):

If anyone else has had this problem and none of the solutions worked, make sure you opened "projectName".xcworkspace and not "projectName".xcodeproj with XCode.

Answer (score 1):

Here are steps that worked for me today:

1. Removed the following inside `ios` directory:

   - `Podfile.lock`
   - `Pods`
2. Re-installed the pod files:

   - `pod install`

I still had the same issue, then I have run the app using Xcode instead of
running from the terminal.

If none of the above fixes it, you might also try removing `node_modules` and run `npm install` or `yarn install` and do the same steps above again.

Comment: do i need to tranfer the whole react native application files or i only need to transfer ios files to mac?